# Triangle number pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing patterns in python but i can't seem to get a this pattern to change.

```
print("\nPattern C")

for c in range(1, 7 + 1):
    for cc in reversed(range(1, c)):
        print(cc, end = '')
    print('')
```

This outputs:

```
Pattern C

1
21
321
4321
54321
654321
```

But i want it to output:

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
654321
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add spaces in some way. One way is to subtract the current counter from a fixed value and print that many spaces.

```
for c in range(1, 7 + 1):
    print(' '*(7-c), end='')
    for cc in reversed(range(1, c)):
        print(cc, end = '')
    print('')
```

As Aaron Hall mentions in comments, there are other ways to produce this output. For example, with a single `print()` (and `num` representing the `7+1` value above, and the `reversed()` replaced with a different `range()` object):

```
for c in range(1, num):
    print(' '*(num-1-c), *range(c-1, 0, -1), sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do (while also changing your code as little as possible)

```
print("\nPattern C")
maxLength = 7
for c in range(1, maxLength + 1):
    s = ''
    for cc in reversed(range(1, c + 1)):
        s += str(cc)
    print(("%" + str(maxLength) + "s")%s)`
```

I didn't change much, I just added string formatting, and I added a "+ 1".

This uses string formatting to right justify each string.
`%10s` justifies a word to the end of a 10 character space.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a format string method after each line to add the space padding.

```
print("\nPattern C")

for c in range(1, 7+ 1):
    line=""
    for cc in reversed(range(1, c)):
        line+=str(cc)
    print('{:>6}'.format(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    Num = ""
    for j in range(1, i + 2):
        Num = str(j) + Num
    print(" " * (N - i) + (Num))


Input:-6
Output: 
         1
        21
       321
      4321
     54321
    654321
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**